# Was ist ein Wort für jemanden, der seinem Professor/Trainer zuhört und der unter anderem deswegen einer der besten oder der beste in diesem Feld ist?

Tags: vocabulary

Das Wort, das ich suche, ist nicht Wunderkind, weil das Wort Wunderkind einen Fokus auf Begabung oder Talent hat und nicht auf Arbeit, Wille etc. Ich suche ein Wort, das ähnlich wie Wunderkind funktioniert, aber dass der Fokus auf Arbeit und Wille ist.

Comment: Soll es auch positive Konnotation haben?

Comment: Wenn ja, würde ich es maximal genießen! Sehr gutes Kommentar.

Answer (score 6):

*Musterschüler* würde passen, für einen der besten Schüler. Ob der nun begabt ist oder fleißig, geht aus dem Wort allerdings nicht eindeutig hervor.

Comment: Vorzeigeschüler wäre noch eine passende Alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Einen besonders ehrgeizigen, auf Leistung bedachten Schüler nennt man abwertend »Streber«.

Comment: Das hat allerdings eine negative Konnotation.